# Run all std input test files in a folder and verify the result? (python)

Tags: python, testing

I have a folder called tests that contains some files. The files are of two kinds, using an example: 01 and 01.a

01 is the input and 01.a is the expected output.

There are many pairs like this.

Normally, I would run `program.py < tests/01` and manually check the output with 01.a.

Is there a way to automate this with many such pairs? Or is there a library that helps with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to get current module name and get answers by this:

```
import sys
import os

current_module_path = sys.modules[__name__].__file__
current_module_name = current_module_path.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split('.')[0]
results_filename = f'{current_module_name}.a'

with open(results_filename) as f:
    expected_results = f.read()
```

If you want to get all files in directory by name (01.py, 02.py, 0n.py) - use this:

```
import os, re
filenames = [f for f in os.listdir('./tests/') if re.match(r'[0-9]{1,2}\.py', f)]
```

Then create another file, import program.py and set filename to class/function.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I can also use "01" as input to the program as well?

Comment: @AkashB Do you want some range input or what?

Comment: so I want the content of "01" to be the standard input to the program and to verify the result with the content in "01.a". Same with all other pairs of files: "02" "02.a", "03" "03.a"....etc.

Comment: @AkashB my code on the top gets expected results by filename (01 -> 01.a, 02 -> 02.a), so you can compare it. expected_results will keep your results from 0n.a file

Comment: yes, true. But can "0n" be used as standard input in the code block above?